# How to get path to S3 assets from Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, asset-sync

**My setup**

I'm using Rails 3, asset_sync and paperclip.

- When I'm developing on my local machine, I want assets to be served **through asset pipeline**.
- In production, I want assets to be served from **S3**.

**My question**

*How can I access to the asset path from Controller/Model/whatever? (The same URL that I get if I use `image_path("favicon.ico")` in views)*

I have seen countless of SO questions, where the accepted answer suggest use of `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("favicon.ico")`. That's fine, BUT, when I try it in production, I get an URL pointing to my production server, NOT to S3.

I added a piece of test code to my production HAML to demonstrate the issue:

`%link{:rel => "image_src", :href => image_path("test.png")}
%link{:rel => "image_src", :href => ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path("test.png")}`

...which generates HTML:

`<link href='http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/test-2cfd63058597b0c73221f3c1988c121e.png' rel='image_src'>
<link href='/assets/test-2cfd63058597b0c73221f3c1988c121e.png' rel='image_src'>`

So, I think **ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path** is not the right way to solve the issue.

I've also seen many answers saying that `view_context` should be used. However, I do not have instance of a controller at the time when I need the URL, so also this approach does not work for me.

**More background (in case you're interested)**

What I'm trying to achieve is to serve Paperclip default image from S3.

`has_attached_file :logo,
  :styles => { ... },
  :default_url => # Here, I need the URL that points to S3, if this is run in production.`

I don't want to hard-code the URL to point to my S3 bucket, since I'd like to serve the file from local machine when I'm developing (as suggested here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1092)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue described here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10051 and which seems to be fixed in Rails 4 with https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12622.

The first discussion describes a possible workaround with an initializer for Rails 3:

```
class ActionController::Base
  def self.helpers
    @helper_proxy ||= begin
      proxy = ActionView::Base.new
      proxy.config = config.inheritable_copy
      proxy.extend(_helpers)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! Good to hear that it has been fixed in 4.